# How to fix "ValueError:Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (0, 1)" in following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I run one py file, In which I gave the path of another file which includes 50 CSV files. When I run the .py file, first 5 CSV files run properly and after 5th it encountered with ValueError.

Firstly I thought it might be the buffer is full so after every iteration, I cleared the buffer and check but the same thing happens.
Then I tried to convert line 130 high_slopes into [high_slopes](mention in the code section) but that doesn't work.

```py
  File "bul_files.py", line 198, in <module>
    trend_data = get_trend_data(price_data)
  File "bul_files.py", line 156, in get_trend_data
    high_trend_data = get_high_trend_data(dataframe)
  File "bul_files.py", line 130, in get_high_trend_data
    high_trend_data = pd.DataFrame(high_slopes,index=dataframe.index[peak_indi
ces],columns=['high_slope'])
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (0, 1)
```

I'm expecting that depending on high_slopes it gives me the proper result that I've written in the code. For 1st 5 files, I got the proper results but I'm not able to get result for remaining files. Please help!

Comment: I'd guess your variable `peak_indices` holds only `False` values

Comment: No, It takes only True values

Comment: Look at the error. `indices imply (0,1)`. This means that whatever you are passing in `index=(....)` has 0 elements, and whatever you are passing in `columns=(....)` has 1 element. Indeed, we know the latter is true: you passed `['high_slope']` to the `columns` argument. But we don't know what `dataframe.index[peak_indices]` return because we don't have acess to this variable. But clearly, it is returning an empty array

Comment: so, what will be the solution? I actually running out of solution....

Comment: well, I dont know why you need to construct your dataframe this way. But you can just do `pd.Dataframe(high_slopes, columns=['high_slope'])` and let pandas use default indexes for that.

Comment: btw, how it actually working for 1st 5 files and not for the rest?

Comment: ```pd.Dataframe(high_slopes, columns=['high_slope'])``` I use this code but it showing following results ```  File "bul_files.py", line 39, in get_latest_peak_info
    latest_high_date = high_data.index.to_pydatetime()[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0```